# Getting an error when trying to make a multiple parameter template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a structure that I just templated. However this gives me the following error.

Error   1   error C3857: 'Cell': multiple template parameter lists are not allowed  c:\code\pg3 project\pg3lab1\pg3lab1\Cell.h  3

```
template<class Offset = signed char, class Symbol = wchar_t>
struct Cell
{
    Offset oX, oY;
    ConsoleColor fg, bg;
    Symbol sym;

    Cell() { }
    Cell(Offset oX, Offset oY, ConsoleColor fg, ConsoleColor bg, Symbol sym);

    bool Show(int left, int top) const;

    Offset& operator[](int index);
    Offset const& operator[](int index) const;
};
```

Comment: This compiles fine. How did you use the templated class?

Comment: I think you does not show the full code. This code should compile fine. Visual C++ compiler usually gives this error when you try to place several template parameter lists before a class template declaration: `template <class T> template <class U> struct S;`.